# Cannot deploy due to missing tile templates in Fiori launchpad designer

Tags: sapui5, tile, sap-fiori, catalog, sap-gateway

After developing a first small application on the SAP web IDE, I want to deploy it. For that I launch the launchpad designer via */UI2/FLPD_CUST* and then create a catalogue. Then I want to add a tile, but no template is proposed to me. So I'm blocked from deploying my application. Below is what I can see and I am missing the standard tile templates:

First step:

[image: First step]

Second step:

[image: Second step]

Third step:

[image: Third step]

Normally we should find the templates there, but they are not there.

Gateway: 740 SP01, SAPUI5 1.44.1

Comment: Do you see tile templates when working in other catalogs in this particular system? If very little is installed, it may be that you'll see the tile templates only after you have done the [LPD_CUST configuration](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/b7/999de9e8be4fa584f99a1082830a32/frameset.htm) for your app.

Aside: It will probably help to go to a later Gateway SP, and to implement the mandatory notes for that SP, to avoid unnecessary troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, there is probably no parameter setting somewhere, the launchpad works when I launch it on another environment.

Comment: No, I don't see the tiles in any other catalogue

Comment: Have you done the [LPD_CUST configuration](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/b7/999de9e8be4fa584f99a1082830a32/frameset.htm) for your app?

Comment: There is a cache table (/UI2/CHIP_CHDR) for the chip type and maybe it is out of sync.
Please run the report /UI2/CHIP_SYNCHRONIZE_CACHE in the Frontend server and check if it helps.